# How to make filter aggregations using PyES

Tags: elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch, pyes, pyelasticsearch

```
{
    "aggs" : {
        "in_stock_products" : {
            "filter" : { "range" : { "stock" : { "gt" : 0 } } },
            "aggs" : {
                "avg_price" : { "avg" : { "field" : "price" } }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How to generate the above query using PyES?